# How to promise / await callback function to be called, when function is passed to another function

Tags: node.js, typescript, apache-kafka

I have a typescript method that is trying to call a method, `on()`, that takes in a callback method. I'd like to have `myConnect()` wait until the callback method is executed. I assume this is a promise, but I'm not sure how to write this method so it waits until the callback is called.

```
  myConnect(): void {
    this.innerProducer.connect();
    this.innerProducer.on("ready", () => {
      Logger.info("producer is ready to produce for topic {}", this.topic);
      this.isReadyToProduce = true;
    });
  }
```

I attempted to use `util.promisify`, but it's not quite right:

```
  async connect2() {
    this.innerProducer.connect();
    const util = require("util");
    const readyCallbackFunc = util.promisify(this.innerProducer.on);

    await readyCallbackFunc("ready", () => {
      Logger.info("producer is ready to produce for topic {}", this.topic);
      this.isReadyToProduce = true;
    });
  }
```

error: `(node:23144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of undefined`

API is defined here:
https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/129cb733f5b3271523fb27cd38c08de0f20e0515/index.d.ts#L196

`on<E extends Events>(event: E, listener: EventListener<E>): this;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `on` function into a Promise.

```
async myConnect(): Promise<void> {
  this.innerProducer.connect();
  await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
   // TODO: Add reject call on some error.

   this.innerProducer.on("ready", () => {
     Logger.info("producer is ready to produce for topic {}", this.topic);
     this.isReadyToProduce = true;

     resolve();
   });
  });
}
```

Then when you need to use use use `await myConnect()` or `myConnect().then(() => { some code here! });`

Comment: compiler says that 1 parameter is expected to `resolve()`

Comment: What does exactly typescript transpiler say? Oh and I probably made a mistake in the code I will update it now

Comment: Thanks. compiler says: `src/kafka/producer/kafka.topic.producer.ts:36:9 - error TS2794: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0. Did you forget to include 'void' in your type argument to 'Promise'?

36         resolve();

Comment: await new Promise<void>(...)

Comment: Just add `<void>` to the `new Promise` call

Comment: I have changed the code sample. Now it should work with your TS settings. `resolve` is a function to change actually resolve a promise.

Comment: OK. I and I'm looking at `reject`, and it's just an `any`, but not sure what to do with that? It's just a failure of the promise I"m making myself?

Comment: You should call `reject` with an error if any happened. Read this https://javascript.info/promise-basics and please mark the answer as correct if that solved your problem